# Elasticsearch Concurrent indexing requests with refresh=wait_for

Tags: elasticsearch

According to documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html) the `refresh=wait_for` parameter has the following limitations:

> Never start multiple refresh=wait_for requests in a row. Instead batch them into a single bulk request with refresh=wait_for ...

Can anyone explain why this limitation exists? And how relevant it is?

As we have multiple concurrent incoming requests we cannot batch them. Is it ok for max. 60 or 120 requests per second to use `refresh=wait_for` anyway?

Comment: The real question would be to know why are you using "wait_for" in the first place? The corollary question is how long is your current `refresh_interval`?

Comment: refresh_interval is set to 1 second.

We like to switch to `wait_for` because after the indexing request we signal our downstream services that the document now is there, but in some cases it wasn't yet, causing the services to fail.

So we decided to wait to mitigate downstream services failure.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The reason it's not a good idea to start multiple request with wait_for is mainly in the case you're updating several indices, but if all your indexing requests update the same index, then the effect would not be that bad, because the index would refresh for all requests **at the same time**. In all cases, this needs to be tested and tried out and see how it's working for you.